# Autoconf cannot find config.status

Tags: build, autoconf, openwebrtc, autogen

When I run `./autogen.sh` on **https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc** I get this:

```
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoheader --force
autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
configure.ac:21: installing './compile'
configure.ac:28: installing './config.guess'
configure.ac:28: installing './config.sub'
configure.ac:15: installing './install-sh'
configure.ac:15: installing './missing'
ext/sctp/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
autoreconf: no config.status: cannot re-make
autoreconf: Leaving directory `.'
```

Should I manually create `config.status` or the fact this file is missing indicates something before it went wrong? Or should I add some command arguments?
I didn't find a lot of additional info about it.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`autoconf` ended up with error. When I fixed it `config.status` was created and everything went as normal

Comment: Could you please write in details what exactly was done? as I don't understand anything from your post and have faced with the same shi.. problem

Comment: i fixed it with running `./configure` that appeared only when `./autogen.sh` failed